# Reorder attributes of data table

Tags: r, loops, attributes, data.table

Consider the following data table

```
t <- data.table(user1 = c(1,2), user3 = c(5,6), user2=c(3,4))
```

This will make `t[[1]] = t$user1 , t[[2]] = t$user3 , t[[3]] = t$user2`

How can I order the attributes of t to make `t[[2]] = t$user2 , t[[3]] = t$user3`

The reason is that I would like to loop through attributes (let's say through all userx) while keeping its order `x` for further use.

My loop is

```
for (i in 1: length(t)) 
{#i is used here}
```

instead of

```
for (attr in names(t))
```

Is there a way to achieve this in R ?

Comment: see `?data.table::setcolorder`.

Comment: Perfect, @mt1022. In fact my attributes are ordered as : abc_user, def_user, Others, user1, user2, user3, .. user100. I would like to push `Others` at the end while retaining the rest. How can I do that without indicating explicitly all users ?

Comment: something like `setcolorder(t, c(names(t)[names(t) != 'Others'], 'Others'))`?

Comment: Charming. Thanks @mt1022

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to place one variable ("other" in your case), you can simply generate a new variable which will be automatically placed as a last column. Then you can remove the original variable ("other") and rename the newly generated variable. Take your provided example for illustration:

```
t <- data.table(user1 = c(1,2), user3 = c(5,6), user2=c(3,4))
t$user4<- t$user3
t$user3<-NULL
names(t)[names(t) == "user4"] <- "user3"
t
##    user1 user2 user3
## 1:     1     3     5
## 2:     2     4     6
```